# How to draw parametric 3d curve with smoothing in R?

Tags: r, 3d, plot, curve-fitting, curve

I have the data which are parametric 3d curve:

```
    t        x       y       z
0.000    3.734   2.518  -0.134    
0.507    2.604   9.059   0.919
0.861    1.532  11.584  -0.248
1.314    1.015   1.886  -0.325
1.684    2.815   4.596   3.275
1.938    1.359   8.015   2.873
2.391    1.359   8.015   2.873
..............................
```

I found [scatterplot3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/index.html) and [plot3d](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/rgl/html/plot3d.html) really cool. But I need a smooth 3d curve.

How can I plot it in R?

Comment: Do you have the parametric function of `t` that generated the `xyz` values? But even if not, you want to interpolate in 3d between the points you already have -  and do better than a simple linear interpolation?

Comment: `scatterplot3d` has a `type` argument, which you can set to `"l"` to link your points and form a curve.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I want something better than simple linear interpolation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `spline` to interpolate between your points and smooth the curve.

```
d <- read.delim(textConnection(
"t x y z
0.000 3.734 2.518 -0.134
0.507 2.604 9.059 0.919
0.861 1.532 11.584 -0.248
1.314 1.015 1.886 -0.325
1.684 2.815 4.596 3.275
1.938 1.359 8.015 2.873
2.391 1.359 8.015 2.873"
), sep=" ")
ts <- seq( from = min(d$t), max(d$t), length=100 )
d2 <- apply( d[,-1], 2, function(u) spline( d$t, u, xout = ts )$y ) 
library(scatterplot3d)
p <- scatterplot3d(d2, type="l", lwd=3)
p$points3d( d[,-1], type="h" )
```

[image: Smoothed curve]

As per @Spacedman's comment, you could also use `rgl`:
this allows you to interactively rotate the scene.

```
library(rgl)
plot3d( d2, type="l", lwd=5, col="navy" )
points3d(d[,-1])
spheres3d(d[,-1], radius=.1, col="orange")
segments3d( matrix( t( cbind( d[,-1], d[,2:3], 0 ) ), nc=3, byrow=TRUE ) )
planes3d(0,0,1,0, col="yellow", alpha=.5)  # Plane z=0
```

[image]

Comment: Bravo! I'd give this more cred if I could.

Comment: I guess this is how they create rollercoasters!